# Google Calendar API is not returning all events

Tags: php, json, api, calendar

I have a query that displays 250 events that my local clubs calendar has added to their calendar.

It currently only goes up until 2021 which is not what I want.  How do I get it to show current dates, do I have to change a setting or am I supposed to use the next page token?

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'.$calName.'/events?key='.$key.'');

// Converts it into a PHP object
$data = json_decode($json, JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY); 

$length = count($data['items']);
$i=0;

while ($length != $i){
     
    print_r($data['items'][$i]['start']);
    print_r("<br/>");

 $i ++;
```

[minimal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EYle.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Google Calendar API documentation for the `maxResults` optional query parameter](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list#maxResults):

> Maximum number of events returned on one result page. […] By default the value is 250 events. The page size can never be larger than 2500 events.

So by default, a single request is limited to 250 events but you can increase this to 2500. You may need to set up paging even if you set the `maxResults` to the maximum 2500.

Comment: Thank you I missed that part of the Api. I will read it now, thank you again.